# Curvature in hyperbolic manifolds

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, curvature

I was wondering that, if I have a manifold $M=\mathbb{H}^n / \Gamma$ (where $\Gamma$ is a discrete group of isometries of the hyperbolic space), how would the curvature elements of this manifold change? More concretely, I mean if the Riemann or Ricci tensors coincide with those of $\mathbb{H}^n$.

My intuition says no, since both tensors are locally defined and they are just a function of the metric for the Levi Civita connection.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: What does "coincide" even mean in this context? These are different manifolds. You can say that these manifolds are locally isometric and local isometry preserves all the curvature tensors. My suggestion is to read a Riemannian Geometry textbook since you do not seem to have a solid grasp of the concepts you are asking about.

Comment: The Riemann Curvature Tensor is entirely determined by the sectional curvatures and vice-versa. As such, if two metrics on a manifold both have the same sectional curvatures everywhere, they must have the same Riemann tensor everywhere. In particular this holds true for hyperbolic manifolds (under the definition constant sectional curvatures $-1$)